# Rake : List / Remove custom rake task in specific environment (development / production )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler

Is there any way to make my custom rake tasks only listed in `development` environment but not in `production` and `QA`?

I mean, when I invoke `bundle exec rake -T` in `qa` or `production` env, it should not list my custom `rake tasks` but it should in `development`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to the application `Rakefile` (after `MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks`line):

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  # add here the tasks you want to disable
  tasks_to_disable = [
    "db:drop",
    "db:reset"
  ]
  tasks = Rake.application.instance_variable_get("@tasks")
  tasks.delete_if { |task_name, _| tasks_to_disable.include?(task_name) }
end
```